# Column A and Column B equal new Value for Column C in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have been asked to update some of our SQL fields to a more modern, singular terminology. So now I am in the process of merging 2 columns into one new value and inputting that new value into another table. I know what I want the old to now equal, I am just not sure how to put in to less words and the right terminology to to know how to search for help.

The person who originally designed this database makes things more complicated than it should be. Therefore making somethings difficult to understand and comprehend...

To try to explain.. Currently I am working with the data from TABLE1 and translating it to a new value which will go into TABLE2

UDATE: I originally posed my tables wrong

```
TABLE1                                     TABLE2
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+
|   ID    |   A     |    B    |            |    ID   |    C    |
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+
|   01    | DESCRPT1| STRIPED |            |    01   | ZEBRA   |
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+
|   01    | DESCRPT2|  HORSE  |            |    02   | SNAKE   |
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+
|   02    | DESCRPT1| SLIMEY  |            
+---------+---------+---------+                 
|   02    | DESCRPT2|  ROPE   |            
+---------+---------+---------+  

From TABLE1
If Value DESCRPT1 is 'Striped' and DESCIRP2 is 'Horse'
THEN insert 'Zebra' into TABLE2 column C where TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
If Value DESCRPT1  is 'Slimey' and DESCIRP2 is 'Rope'
THEN insert 'Snake' into TABLE2 column C where TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

NOTE: This is my first post here, so if I am missing any information or doing this wrong. Sorry :(

**UPDATE**

```
tblEngagementAttributes                     tblEngagement
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+---------+
|   ID    |   A     |    B    |            |    ID   |  Client |    C    |
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+---------+
|   01    | DESCRPT1| STRIPED |            |    01   | John    | ZEBRA   |
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+---------+
|   01    | DESCRPT2|  HORSE  |            |    02   | Mark    | SNAKE   |
+---------+---------+---------+            +---------+---------+---------+
|   02    | DESCRPT1| SLIMEY  |            
+---------+---------+---------+                 
|   02    | DESCRPT2|  ROPE   |            
+---------+---------+---------+
```

So a little more information that I'm finding might be beneficial for helping to figure this out.. The table that I am translating the data into is already an existing table. These two tables have a shared foreign key 'ID'

Comment: SQL is a relational database, meaning that it is really good at leveraging relationships between data in tables.  To solve your problem, ideally you would want to have `TABLE2` already computed.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. For your first question, is very well written dont worry.

Comment: I just realized i posed my question wrong..

Comment: You only have `ZEBRA` and `SNAKE`? because if you have more animals like noah, maybe is better use a middle table instead `CASE .. WHEN`

Comment: I update your table, because I guess you mean `DESCRPT2 |  ROPE`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` construct to achieve what you want.  The trick I would point out here is to use a `WHERE` clause on `TABLE1` to restrict to only records which you would certainly want to insert in some form.  If you omitted the `WHERE` clause, the query would still run, but then you would add dummy records for any records in `TABLE1` which you would not want to map to `TABLE2`.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID, C)
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN A = 'STRIPED' AND B = 'HORSE' THEN 'ZEBRA'
            WHEN A = 'SLIMEY'  AND B = 'ROPE'  THEN 'SNAKE'
            ELSE ''
       END
FROM TABLE1
WHERE A = 'STRIPED' AND B = 'HORSE' OR
      A = 'SLIMEY'  AND B = 'ROPE'
```

**Update:**

I gave the above answer to your original question before you changed it.  Try the following query for your updated question:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID, C)
SELECT t.ID,
       CASE WHEN t.ZebraCol >= 2 THEN 'ZEBRA'
            WHEN t.SnakeCol >= 2 THEN 'SNAKE'
            ELSE ''
       END AS C
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
           SUM(CASE WHEN (A = 'DESCRPT1' AND B = 'STRIPED') OR
                         (A = 'DESCRPT2' AND B = 'HORSE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ZebraCol,
           SUM(CASE WHEN (A = 'DESCRPT1' AND B = 'SLIMEY') OR
                         (A = 'DESCRPT2' AND B = 'ROPE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SnakeCol
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY ID
) t
WHERE t.ZebraCol >= 2 OR t.SnakeCol >= 2
```

Comment: @Megan No worries.  Update your question and we will try to answer again.

Comment: Just in case. If you already filter using `WHERE` you dont need the `ELSE` part. Also be carefull of capitalize your constant.  `'Striped' <> 'STRIPED'`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I always prefer to specify an `ELSE` value, even if it should not be reached, because I don't like to rely on the database choosing a value for me.  With regard to the all caps, I just used the data I saw in the sample output tables from the OP.

Comment: Hi Tim, Is me again :). For OP example your second query looks ok. But if OP write this as a very generic sample be carefull because your query say `STRIPED - HORSE` and `HORSE - STRIPED` are both `ZEBRA` because doesnt consider `DESCRPT1` vs `DESCRPT2`

Comment: Trying to update everything to suit the actual DB i'm working on, will keep you posted. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `CASE` statement, I've never done it with `INSERT` before but this should be a good starting point:

```
INSERT into table2(id, c)
    SELECT id,
           CASE WHEN table1.a = 'STRIPED' AND table1.b = 'HORSE' THEN 'ZEBRA'
           CASE WHEN table1.a = 'SLIMEY' AND table1.b = 'ROPE' THEN 'SNAKE'
           ELSE ''
           END
FROM table1
WHERE a = 'STRIPED' AND B = 'HORSE' OR
      a = 'SLIMEY' AND B = 'ROPE'
```

Give it a go.

Tim beat me to it.

Comment: I messed up my initial post. This would be perfect, but unfortunately, the descriptions are entered on multiple lines and not columns.

So I have two (or more for some instances) lines of descriptions for every ID. No a column for each description.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess you have more animals than `ZEBRA` and `SNAKE` so will suggest a more generic solution. First you create one aditional table to store what Descriptor give each animal. This allow you add or change description without affect your query.

```
CREATE TABLE WHAT_IS
    (`W_ID` int, `D1` varchar(7), `D2` varchar(5), `IS_A` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO WHAT_IS
    (`W_ID`, `D1`, `D2`, `IS_A`)
VALUES
    (1, 'STRIPED', 'HORSE', 'ZEBRA'),
    (2, 'SLIMEY', 'ROPE', 'SNAKE')
;
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d8c85/1) This assume each `ID` only have one `'DESCRPT1'` and one `'DESCRPT2'`

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (`ID`, `C`)
SELECT T.`ID`, W.`IS_A` as `C`
FROM (
      SELECT `ID`, 
              MAX(CASE WHEN `A` = 'DESCRPT1' THEN `B` END) as D1,
              MAX(CASE WHEN `A` = 'DESCRPT2' THEN `B` END) as D2
      FROM Table1 t   
      GROUP BY `ID`
     ) T
JOIN WHAT_IS W
  ON T.`D1` = W.`D1`
 AND T.`D2` = W.`D2`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |     C |
|----|-------|
|  1 | ZEBRA |
|  2 | SNAKE |
```